# Increase top row in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table and I want the top row to be larger and the font bold.
But all I get is this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $\frac{a}{b}$& $\frac{a}{\Large \frac{b}{c}}$ &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you know this document? `lshort ` documentation https://ctan.org/search?phrase=lshort

Comment: @pascal974 no   i dont

Comment: you also have `array` documentation, look for `\arraystretch` and `>{\bfseries}`

Comment: `\Large\mathversion{bold}$\frac{a}{b}$` might do it.

Comment: Should only the top row be rendered in **bold**? Pls advise.

Comment: It would help if you provided the full table with some data at least close to what the final table should be. There is a number of solutions and the right answer will be different depending on the content.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? I using `nicematrix` for tables:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \RowStyle[cell-space-bottom-limit=3pt,cell-space-top-limit=6pt,bold]{}
        $\frac{a}{b}$ & $\frac{a}{\displaystyle\frac{b}{c}}$ & text &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
        &  &  &  &  \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

(if you use `nicematrix`, must be compile at least three times.)

[image]